# Using \align inside \cases

Tags: align, cases

The code I was using is this:

```
        \[
    \begin{cases}
    W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) =\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): x_i\in \mathcal{O}_k,\text{ } i\in{\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}} \}\\
    W_n(m_k)=\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k) :x_i\in m_k,\text{ } i\in{\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}}\} \\
    W_n(m_k)^{(m)}=
     \{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k):      
     v(x_i)\geq m/p^{n-1-i},\text{ } i\in{\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}} \}
    \end{cases}\]
```

which worked fine, but when I changed my spacing and all this the third equation ended up being too long meaning I had to change something. I went for the most naive option to just split the definition of the set `\{W_n(m_k)^{(m)}` by simply doing this

```
W_n(m_k)^{(m)}=
     \{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): \\       
     v(x_i)\geq m/p^{n-1-i},\text{ } i\in{\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}} \}
```

but at least I should align the two lines of definition.

How could I do this? (I tried using `\align`, `\aligned` but it seems it doesn't work with `cases`.

Or would there be a 'better' way of writing a set in two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
\[
    \begin{cases}
        W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) = \{X^{(n)} = (x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in W_n(k): x_i \in \mathcal{O}_k,\text{ } i \in{\{0, 1, \cdots, n-1\}} \}\\

        W_n(m_k) = \{X^{(n)} = (x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in W_n(k): x_i \in m_k,\text{ } i \in{\{0, 1, \cdots, n-1\}}\} \\

        W_n(m_k)^{(m)} =
            \{X^{(n)} = (x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in W_n(k): \\
            \hphantom{W_n(m_k)^{(m)} = \strut}v(x_i) \geq m/p^{n-1-i},\text{ } i \in{\{0, 1, \cdots, n-1\}} \}
    \end{cases}
\]
```

`\hphantom` reserves horizontal space, and the `\strut` is just a random trick to add the “after equal sign spacing”. It's not a very pretty solution, though.
On a side-note: adding spaces in your equations should make them easier to work with. They are generally ignored during compilation in maths, so it's convenient to make the code prettier. You can even add linebreaks! ♥
You might also want to consider using something like `\quad`, `\enspace` or one of the various math spaces instead of `\text{ }`.

You might be able to write another solution using `array` and a solitary huge left curly brace in place of the `cases`. Try the following dumb example to see what I mean:

```
$\left\{
    \begin{array}{@{} r l @{}}
        x               &= 1 \\
        \mathit{plop}   &= 2
    \end{array}
\right.$
```

I don't have the time to do it myself right now, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would align at the `=` signs and the third equation is split so that the `\geq` operator is aligned to the `=` above. I changed also a couple of things; the outer delimiters are changed to `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` and the `\cdots` are changed to `\dotsc`, which means *dots between commas*.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{cases}
 \begin{aligned}
  W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) &=\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): x_i\in \mathcal{O}_k,\, i \in{\{0,1,\dotsc, n-1\}}\bigr\}\\
  W_n(m_k)           &=\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): x_i\in m_k,\, i\in{\{0,1,\dotsc, n-1\}}\bigr\} \\
  W_n(m_k)^{(m)}     &=\begin{aligned}[t]\bigl\{X^{(n)} &=(x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): \\      
                                                 v(x_i) &\geq m/p^{n-1-i},\, i\in{\{0,1,\dotsc, n-1\}} \bigr\} \end{aligned}
 \end{aligned}
\end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX offers lot of possibilities.  Here is another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) = \bigl\{ X^{(n)}= (x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1}) \in
      W_n(k) \mid x_i \in \mathcal{O}_k,\ 0 \le i \le n-1 \bigl\}\\
    W_n(m_k) = \bigl\{ X^{(n)}= (x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1}) \in W_n(k)
      \mid x_i\in m_k,\ 0 \le i \le n-1 \bigl\}\\
    W_n(m_k)^{(m)} = \bigl\{ X^{(n)} = (x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1}) \in
      W_n(k) \mid {}\\[-2pt]
    \hfill v(x_i)\geq m/p^{n-1-i},\ 0 \le i\le n-1 \bigl\}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `matrix*[l]` environment, or the `empheq` package and slightly change the layout:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

  \[
    \begin{cases}
    W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) =\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): x_i\in \mathcal{O}_k,\text{ } i\in \{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}\bigr \}\\[1ex]
    W_n(m_k)=\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k) :x_i\in m_k,\text{ } i\in \{0,1,\cdots, n-1\} \bigr\} \\[1ex]
    W_n(m_k)^{(m)}=
     \biggl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): \:\Bigm\vert
     \begin{matrix*}[l]v(x_i)\geq m/p^{n-1-i},\text{ }\\[-0.5ex] i\in\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}\end{matrix*}\biggr \}
    \end{cases}\]


    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace\,, right ={\qquad( i\in \{0,1,\cdots, n-1\})} ]{align*}
     & W_n(\mathcal{O}_k) =\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): x_i\in \mathcal{O}_k \}\bigr \}\\[1ex]
     & W_n(m_k)=\bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k) :x_i\in m_k \bigr\} \\[1ex]
     & W_n(m_k)^{(m)} = \Bigl\{X^{(n)}=(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\in W_n(k): v(x_i)\geq m/p^{n-1-i} \Bigr \}
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]